# Why does Intellij stop at "ghost" breakpoints

Tags: node.js, debugging, intellij-idea

This is driving me insane. I have a nodejs v10.17 (loopback v3) server running in Intellij (Build #IU-201.7846.76, built on June 1, 2020).  Every time that I restart then it feels the need to stop at what seems to be arbitrary breakpoints- e.g. in the top "require" statements.

I have restarted Intellij several times.  I have dropped and recreated node_modules.  I have cleared all breakpoints that I can see in the Debugging View (these ghost ones don't appear in the list of breakpoints).

When stopped at the breakpoint and I examine the call stack - none of the rows have a breakpoint set or visible.

Where else can I look - what else can I try?  It is really annoying.

Comment: can be an issue with sourcemaps, or even with Node V8 engine itself - hard to tell without the project

Comment: thanks for that @lena - i will follow that trail.  unfortunately i have nothing that i can upload/attach to be more useful.